# Debugging commands (step over/into) cause unhandled exceptions

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crash, debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 on a 64-bit version of Vista.  After my program stops on one of my breakpoints, I can't step over or into the current line without either an Illegal Instruction exception or an Access Violation exception being thrown by my application.  If I right-click on the next line and choose "Run to here" (equivalent to "Step over"), it works fine.

Addendum: there is nothing in any watch windows.

Also, here's something I forgot to mention:  if I attach to the process, everything works just fine.

Has anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: Had this problem myself, and fixed it by disabling RPC debugging as stated in the accepted answer.  The specific symptom was the Output message (and dialog box) saying "Unhandled exception at 0x0501f77e in MyApplicationD.exe: 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction." (I note it to help others search for same issue.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mos, I was wondering have you resolved this problem (since I also have it with VS2005 and VS2008 on 64-bit Win7)?

Edit: "Uncheck Tools/Options/Debugging/Native/Enable RPC debugging" was suggested in comment, and seems to be the answer.

Comment: I have not.  I've wiped my system and reinstalled everything (including upgrading to Windows 7), and it still happens.  At this point I'm leaning toward it being a hardware issue.

Comment: Could you try to uncheck Tools/Options/Debugging/Native/Enable RPC debugging? Does it help? It does at my place, although, I'm not sure for how long. :)

Comment: Somehow, I missed your comment when it was posted. I'm glad I ended up reviewing these answers again, "just to be sure." Sure enough, disabling RPC debugging did the trick. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the exceptions in your application, or Visual Studio itself?

I would start by doing Clean on the entire solution then Build again.  Sometimes if your binaries get out of sync you can get weird behavior when debugging.

Comment: I updated the question to answer your question.

Yes, I have clean built my project.  No dice.  It's really frustrating.  :/

Answer (score 0):

Is your application multithreaded?

In case it is:

Are you shure the Access violation is thrown by the thread that you are debuging ?
Did you freeze all other threads?

Comment: It is multi-threaded, but freezing the other threads does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any function calls in any of the watch windows, clear them out.