# Debugging on Win7 HyperV VM, get multiple instances of "0xC0000096 Privileged instruction" exceptions

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, hyper-v

When I debug a large app (with VS2008) that I maintain on a Windows 7 Hyper V VM, it seems that once I hit a breakpoint, VS constantly throws 0xC0000096 Privileged instruction exceptions( or 0x00000005 Access violation reading 0x03A6E7EB).

It doesn't seem to matter where the breakpoints are set either. I can do exactly the same things on a Win2k3 box with VS2008 installed, but never get these faults. The code & the settings are the same. When I first installed VS2008 & compiled & debugged the app these exceptions weren't being thrown - it only started happening after a couple of weeks. Is this a Hyper V/virtual machine issue or what?

There's not much point supplying any code as it seems independent of that, though if any more info is needed I'll try to supply it.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer may be here: [Debugging commands (step over/into) cause unhandled exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836770/debugging-commands-step-over-into-cause-unhandled-exceptions)

Uncheck the "Enable RPC Debugging" option in Tools->Options->Debugging->Native

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I can - haven't used Win7 VM since this issue, but it sounds a likely cause of my problem