# Application crashes while using the scroll bars in winForm Datagrid view

Tags: c#

Hi all i have a background worker thread and some unmanaged code dlls , In progress changed event of background worker . I will get the data from my database in a datatable and make this table as my DataSource. But when i use the scrollbards od DataGridView my application crashes.when I try to debug the application it gives "Unhandled exception in TestExe.exe : 0xC0000096: Privileged Instruction.

Comment: You have to give some more info. Is the BGW accessing the same datasource objects? any events?

Comment: BGW is using the same Datasource objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why your scrollbars are crashing, but the answer to the "Unhandled exception in TestExe.exe : 0xC0000096: Privileged Instruction" message in the debugger may be here:

- [Debugging commands (step over/into) cause unhandled exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836770/debugging-commands-step-over-into-cause-unhandled-exceptions)

Uncheck the "Enable RPC Debugging" option in Tools->Options->Debugging->Native