# VS 2010 (fresh install (twice) SP1Rel too) start debugging gives 0x800703e9 vs. start runs normally

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am talking about the most simple of examples - see below - clearly something is corrupted. Here is the full out and errror text:

New Findings!!! Started up Visual Studio 2008 -- been using for years but for C++, built a new solution from this test5.cs one, and guess what? . . . When start with debugging -- EXACTLY the same ERROR!!! Additionally, I built several types of tiny test programs in C++ including a CLR console application ..... these all work correctly via 'start debugging'....

HELP!

---

```
    <small><small>'test5.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'<br>
          'test5.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'<br>
          'test5.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'<br>
          'test5.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'<br>
          'test5.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'<br>
          'test5.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'<br>
          'test5.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'<br>
          'test5.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
          'C:\projects\test5\test5\test5\bin\Debug\test5.vshost.exe'<br>
          The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x3518) has exited with code 0
          (0x0).<br>
          The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x36a8) has exited with
          code 0 (0x0).<br>
          'test5.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded
          'C:\projects\test5\test5\test5\bin\Debug\test5.exe', Symbols
          loaded.<br>
          Ignoring managed exception from unknown thread.The program
          '[6748] test5.vshost.exe: Managed (v2.0.50727)' has exited
          with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).</small></small>
```

---

If I just run the test program -- no errors and it runs correctly....

Also importantly --- if I go into program files and under 'debug' and check Enable unmanaged code debugging' -- the start of debug works correctly then as well...... no errors.. ouput trace for this case has been added after the code example below...

I believe this problem is also behind the next question I am going to be posting about matching .PDB files being reported as not matching during a remote debug session.....

here is the example program -- but it doesn't really matter -- all C# examples I have tried are behaving this way.....

Thanks in advance, Kevin Waite

---

```
using System;


namespace test5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 0;

            while (true)
            {

                System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World! {0} ", x );

                ++x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\projects\test5\test5\test5\bin\Debug\test5.exe', No native symbols in symbol file.
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Google\Google Desktop Search\GoogleDesktopNetwork3.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.6001.18000_none_5cdbaa5a083979cc\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Program Files\Google\Google Desktop Search\GoogleDesktopNetwork3.dll'
'test5.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll'
'test5.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1998) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a\msvcr80.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Culture.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Culture.dll'
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\c068708e16abf0be77a21b9f29817d83\mscorlib.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test5.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'test5.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\projects\test5\test5\test5\bin\Debug\test5.exe', Symbols loaded.
'test5.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
```

Comment: The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x14b0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x328c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'test5.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\projects\test5\test5\test5\bin\Debug\test5.exe', Symbols loaded.
Ignoring managed exception from unknown thread.The program '[12684] test5.vshost.exe: Managed (v2.0.50727)' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).

Comment: That error code is a stackoverflow exception.  Since it only happens when debugging do you have NT_SYMBOL_PATH set?  Perhaps it is pointing to some corrupt PDBs?

Comment: You should have posted the trace you got after enabling unmanaged debugging.  Still, this is heavily environmental, crapola like virus scanners or Lord knows what injecting code into your process.  You'll need to get your machine stable again.

Comment: I added the trace/output for when it works with the checked [x] for unmanaged debugging..... I have done a complete install twice, I am asking here because I need to beable to debug and can't -- this machine is stable showing no signs of other problems.... and for NT_SYMBOL_PATH it is not set.... ???

Comment: Could this question's answer be a solution to your problem? They sound very similar...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836770/debugging-commands-step-over-into-cause-unhandled-exceptions

Comment: New Findings!!! Started up Visual Studio 2008 -- been using for years but for C++, built a new project from this test4.cs one, and guess what -- when start with debugging -- EXACTLY the same ERROR!!!